# How do I override a redirect_to in Rails/RefineryCMS/Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, refinerycms

I'm trying to override this method and this redirect:

https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/master/authentication/app/controllers/refinery/passwords_controller.rb#L39

I have this:

```
Refinery::PasswordsController.class_eval do
  layout 'layouts/application'
  after_filter :redirect_to_our_login, only: :create

  def redirect_to_our_login
    redirect_to main_app.sign_in_community_members_path
  end
```

But of course it is giving me the `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`. How can I nullify the first redirect_to and use my own redirect_to path?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just copying the whole method and changing that one line (and added fully qualified names to the classes).